# Using string functions, how i get values form html attributes in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have html code like that:

```
<div class="topright">
    <a href="" TARGET="_parent" title="News Letter" >
       <img border="none" src="/images/newsletter-button.gif' alt="News Letter" />
     </a>
</div>
```

I am developing function findvalue in C#:

```
if (line.Contains("title"))
{
    sTitle = findvalue("title", line);
}
```

`findvalue` function is simple string opreations function which work like that
for this line `<a href="" TARGET="_parent" title="News Letter" >`
find function will retrun News Letter value, similarly I will get value of other attributes like href, src atc

Comment: If you are wanting to parse the HTML, your best bet will be to use a library, like [the HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Please specify reason you are doing it (education, assignment, code to be used). Depending on the reson answers will be different. Note that HTMLAgility pack is traditional answer to this question...

Comment: For one scenario on a single page, should I use this library or my custom function?

Comment: for my project but for one scenario on a single page.

Comment: Than most likely you want to use existing library - it does not look like you are interested in learning all intricacies of parsing markup yourself.

Comment: Much better is to use HtmlAgilityPack without waste time n effort,Thank you guys...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much better is try to use HtmlAgilityPack without waste time n effort,Thank you guys...

Answer (score 1):

You can use XML schema related classes for the same.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

public class Sample
{

    public static void Main()
    {

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml("<input title='Meluha' Value='1-861001-75-7'>" +
                    "<title>The Imortals of Meluha</title>" +
                    "</input>");

        XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;

        XmlNode value = doc.SelectNodes("//input/@value")[0];

        Console.WriteLine("Inner text: " + value.InnerText);

    XmlNode value = doc.SelectNodes("//title/@value")[0];

    Console.WriteLine("Title text: " + value.InnerText);
     } 
}
```

Comment: But HTML is not quite XML. Will it work for self closing html tags?